# protecting range in anonymously shared doc not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

I have a shared spreadsheet that can be edited by anyone who's got the link. Now I'd like to setup a protected range that can only edited by me, the owner.

Unfortunatly this is not working for me. I can not edit the permissions for the range in question, it just displays a Box similar to:

```
    Visibility Options

    Save       Cancel
```

Ist this expected behavior? A bug? Not implemented yet?

tx for info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to protect certain cell and allow anyone to edit other cells.  It a workaround for now until Google improves this feature.

- Go to Format -> Named and Protected Cells
- Create separate Regions for the data you want to protect and for the data you want to be edited.
- Remove any existing protections
- Share the spreadsheet so that it is read-only for everyone
- Go back to Named and Protected Cells and create sharing for the
  regions you want to be protected
- When creating the protection, "everyone" should be listed as Read Only (you can't modify this, it's inherited from the current global sharing of the spreadsheet.)
- Do not create any protection for the regions you want everyone to be
  able to edit
- Exit out of the spreadsheet and then go back in (not sure if this step is
  required, but this is what I did)
- Now re-share the spreadsheet so that "everyone" can edit
- Sign-out of your Google account and open the public link to the
  spreadsheet.  After the spreadsheet loads, the protected regions
  should be read-only (grey hash lines across them) and the input
  regions should be editable by everyone

This finally worked for me.  Hope it works for everyone else.

Answer (score 4):

Carlton's answer worked for me, but after reading it I think I have a better understanding of the issue and a shorter workaround. It seems that the range protection value (view/edit) is taken from spreadsheet's general protection value at the time the range protection is defined.

Thus you could do with a simpler workaround:

- share the spreadsheet as "view only" for everyone
- for each range you wish to protect:

  - create a named range
  - mark it as protected (ignore the fact that it is marked "edit")
- share the spreadsheet as "edit" for everyone

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

user1958927's assessments seem to be correct - it kind of boils down to stripping it all to View Only for anonymous, then naming some ranges and protecting those.  after opening it up to anonymous the named ranges stay protected.

furthermore, i found that any changes to the named ranges (remove a column, for example) will open that column for editing by anonymous.

handy catch and this makes google spreadsheets useful for large groups without craziness about logins to protect big chunks from inadvertent changes.

if you can deal with the gray diagonal lines all over the protected cells.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the stripping grey lines, anyone can go to View and uncheck "protected ranges". It cleans the screen and the cells remain protected.