# Google Apps Scripts: most efficient way to programmatically edit a view only Google Sheet via a button?

Tags: javascript, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

**Goal**: Within Google Sheets, I want to give users view only access to certain files, while also allowing them to programmatically edit those files. This way they can't manually edit the files. Users will click a button to trigger editing on the view only files.

**Example**: The user will enter data into Sheet A for which they have edit access. Upon clicking a button on Sheet A, the data entered on Sheet A will be copied to the last empty row in an existing sheet, Sheet B. The user will have view only access to Sheet B. Note that I'm using Sheet A and Sheet B to refer to separate files, each with a single sheet.

**Solution A**: Taken from [Google Apps Script - Is it possible to allow change to some cell in Sheets only through GoogleAppScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794448/google-apps-script-is-it-possible-to-allow-change-to-some-cell-in-sheets-only). Develop a web app that copies data from Sheet A to Sheet B and runs as the owner of Sheet B. Display the web app link in a dialogue box within Sheet A that requires the user to click the link to complete execution. My problem with this is that I don't want the user to have to click a link. All I want them to do is click a button. A solution to this could be to have the button automatically open and then close the web app link.

**Solution B**: Taken from [How to allow onEdit function to affect protected cell in a Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871241/how-to-allow-onedit-function-to-affect-protected-cell-in-a-google-sheet). Develop a trigger that copies the data and runs as the owner of Sheet B. Because triggers don't run on files with view only access, I would have to 1) give the user edit access to Sheet B and 2) protect all of Sheet B to prevent the user from manually editing Sheet B.

**Solution C** (bouncing off of solution B): I could instead use a simple onOpen trigger. When the user clicks the button, after doing some stuff, Sheet B is opened. Then, within the onOpen trigger I would have to call to open the file again. That's because the first open would be carried out by the user with view only access. The second open within the trigger would open the file as the owner and allow programmatic editing. Then, the data can be copied and the file closed.

**Solution D**: This was the first solution I thought of before discovering the above solutions. Via a button on Sheet A, programmatically 1) copy the *contents* of Sheet B into a new Sheet, Sheet C, for which the user will be the owner (edit access); 2) paste the contents of Sheet A to the last empty row of Sheet C; 3) change the ownership of Sheet C to the desired owner; and 4) delete Sheet B. I don't like this because the file ID of the "copy to" sheet will persistently change and I'm creating an extra file.

**Question**: After ruling out solution D, what is the most efficient and least error prone solution that can be initiated by a user clicking a button?

I've don't this type of thing in Excel using the password protect feature, but I'm new to programming for Google Sheets.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to do something like A but use an API.

- Sheet A - user can edit
- Sheet B - user can't edit
- Sheet B exposes an API as a web-app

  - The web-app runs as the owner of Sheet B
- Sheet A button will read data from Sheet A and make call to Sheet B's API that will update

Let me know if I need to elaborate.